# Sort a list of years within a cell in openrefine

Tags: sorting, openrefine

like on the title, I've a dataset with journals. For each journal I've got a cell with those mixed dates:

1690 -- 1686 -- 1716 -- 1726 -- 1683 -- 1730 -- 1684 -- 1715 -- 1693 -- 1712 -- 1695 -- 1688 -- 1724 -- 1685 -- 1692 -- 1707 -- 1702 -- 1731 -- 1710 -- 1709 -- 1704 -- 1696 -- 1687 -- 1699 -- 1708 -- 1703 -- 1691 -- 1697 -- 1720 -- 1694 -- 1714 -- 1729 -- 1721 -- 1713 -- 1725 -- 1705 -- 1727 -- 1711 -- 1719 -- 1728 -- 1723 -- 1717 -- 1718 -- 1700 -- 1689 -- 1722 -- 1701 -- 1698 -- 1706

How can I sort the dates and take just the first and last publishing dates?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you need, but if I'm reading it right, then this should do it:

```
value.split(' -- ').sort()[0]
value.split(' -- ').sort()[-1]
```

The first one gives you the lowest value, the second the highest value. For this data, you get 1683 and 1731.

You can use "Add column based on this column" twice to get the start and end years in different cells, or you can concatenate the values again with "+", like this:

```
value.split(' -- ').sort()[0] + "-" + value.split(' -- ').sort()[-1]
```

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks